# Does every element of an integral domain have an inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading a first course in algebra 7th edition written by John B. Fraleigh. I have seen the following two definitions:

> 1) A **field** is a commutative ring in which every nonzero element has
>   multiplicative inverse.
>
> 2) An **integral domain** is a commutative ring with unity 1 and
>   containing no zero divisors.

Then i saw a picture in the book that shows fields as subsets of integral domains like in the following picture:

[image]

**My question is**, how do we understand from these two definitions that fields are subsets of integral domains? In the definition of integral domain, i do not see anything saying that every element in the ring should have an inverse, it just says that there must be a multiplicative identity. Am i missing something or is there something missing in the definitions?

Thank you

Comment: The answer to your title question is no. This (not amazingly useful) picture means that every field is an integral domain. So assume $F$ is a field and show it contains no zero divisor.

Comment: @julien oh ok, i interpreted it as a subset. Thanks

Comment: @CutieKrait , do you mean every field is an integral domain?

Comment: yes‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: every finite integral domain is a field and thus has inverse for each element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily the case that every element in an integral domain has a multiplicative inverse.

Every field is an integral domain, but not every integral domain is a field. Hence we have that the set of all fields is a proper subset of the set of all integral domains.

Comment: Thank you, i understand now

Comment: @amWhy: that is excellent feedback! :-0 +1

Comment: Yes, that's always rewarding, @Amzoti!

Answer (score 2):

As already noticed, every field is an integral domain but the converse doesn't hold (take for example $\mathbb{Z}$). In order to show that a field $F$ is an integral domain, suppose $a,b\in F$ are such that $ab=0$ and assume $a$ is not zero. Then since every non zero element in a field is invertible, one has
$$ab=0\implies a^{–1}ab=0\implies b=0. $$ Similarly if $b\neq 0$ one gets that a must be zero and hence $F$ is an integral domain.